# Sending a Message with Spring Cloud Stream and RabbitMq changes ID

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream and RabbitMq to exchange Messages between different microservices.

Thats my setup to publish a message.

```
public interface OutputChannels {
  static final String OUTPUT_CHANNEL = "outputChannel";

  @Output
  MessageChannel outputChannel();
}
```

.

```
@EnableBinding(OutputChannels.class)
@Log4j
public class OutputProducer {

  @Autowired
  private OutputChannels outputChannels;

  public void createMessage(MyContent myContent) {
    Message<MyContent> message = MessageBuilder
      .withPayload(myContent)
      .build();
    outputChannels.outputChannel().send(message);
    log.info("Sent message: " + message.getHeaders().getId() + myContent);
  }
}
```

And the setup to receive the message

```
public interface InputChannels {
  String INPUT_CHANNEL = "inputChannel";

  @Input
  SubscribableChannel inputChannel();
}
```

.

```
@EnableBinding(InputChannels.class)
@Log
public class InputConsumer {

  @StreamListener(InputChannels.INPUT_CHANNEL)
  public void receive(Message<MyContent> message) {

    MyContent myContent = message.getPayload();
    log.info("Received message: " + message.getHeaders().getId() + ", " + myContent);
  }
}
```

I am able to successfully exchange messages with this setup. I would expect, that the IDs of the sent message and the received message are equal. But they are always different UUIDs.

Is there a way that the message keeps the same ID all the way from the producer, through the RabbitMq, to the consumer?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Messaging messages are immutable; they get a new ID each time they are mutated.

You can use a custom header or `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID` to convey a constant value; in most use cases, the correlation id header is set by the application to the ID header at the start of a message's journey.

Comment: Custom header means, that i add a custoum value with   .setHeader(headerName, headerValue) in the MessageBuilder?

How does IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID work? Do i have to set it manually?  `new IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor(message).getCorrelationId()` is always `null`

Comment: Yes; you have to set it at the start; most people simply copy the ID of the initial message. It's used by the framework for components like aggregator but you can use it for your purpose (or choose a custom header).